# coffescript is giving error in my project which before works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, railscasts

I am looking this video http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised
This is my coffescript code

```
jQuery ->
  $('#employee_material_asset_tokens').tokenInput '/assets.json'
    theme: 'facebook'
    prePopulate: $('#employee_material_asset_tokens').data('load')
```

It works fine before but now it gives me error like

```
ExecJS::ProgramError at /employee/reviews
Error: Parse error on line 5: Unexpected 'INDENT'
  (in /home/prem/rails/heronhrm/app/assets/javascripts/employee/assets.js.coffee)
```

I am confuse i did not change code It works fine before ..
what could be the reason
when i change this code like

```
jQuery ->
$('#employee_material_asset_tokens').tokenInput '/assets.json'
theme: 'facebook'
prePopulate: $('#employee_material_asset_tokens').data('load')
```

then token input works but prepopulate and theme doesnot work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you're just missing a `,` after `'/assets.json'`.  Your code should look like

```
$('#employee_material_asset_tokens').tokenInput '/assets.json',
  theme: 'facebook'
  prePopulate: $('#employee_material_asset_tokens').data('load')
```